# How to resize div width with window scroll(jquery) - but only 1/3 of the divs width in the css

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/95EtZ/1/

There is the problem half solved in action.

Right now it's set up with the containers width hardcoded in the javascript.

I need the js to grab the width of the container div - resize it with window scroll. but only resize it 1/3 of the #container divs width.

The way it's set up currently is, you have to set the script manually to the width of the div in the css. I want to be able to change the width of the div in the css and have the js grab it and only allow the user to have it resize 1/3 of it's width as they reach the very bottom of the window.

Answer (score 1):

I posted answer here in code:

http://jsfiddle.net/95EtZ/11/

Width is taken from node and resize is going from 100% to 33% at bottom.